# ActiveSheet vs Application.ActiveSheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using the following method to execute macro's on whichever active sheet the user has in the foreground, since forever.

```
 Public Sub MySub()
     Dim ws as Worksheet
     Set ws = ActiveSheet
     'Execute some code
     Debug.Print ws.Name
 End Sub
```

Up until yesterday, this has executed as expected and `ActiveSheet` has always returned the `ActiveSheet` that currently is in the foreground, or has focus, from executing the macro through the View->Macros->Run Dialog.  Regardless of which `Workbook` the code was executing from.

For some reason very recently, I ran into an issue where `ActiveSheet` was returning the last `ActiveSheet` of the `Workbook` the code was executing from, regardless if I had another book open and it had focus.

I ran this a few times and reproduced this unexpected behavior. After I was satisfied that I hadn't lost my mind, I swapped out `Set ws = ActiveSheet` for `Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet` and the it behaves as expected. The sheet running in the foreground is returned.

Question Time:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Has anyone else experienced this, or able to reproduce this?
3. Is this new, and do I need to go back through all my old macro's and change `ActiveSheet` to `Application.ActiveSheet`?

Comment: you need to say `activeworkbook` .activesheet

Comment: `ActiveSheet` is equivalent to `Application.ActiveSheet` **unless** you are running some code in the code module `ThisWorkbook`, where it would mean `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`. Are you running a macro located in `ThisWorkbook` by any chance?

Comment: You are correct. `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` and `Application.ActiveSheet` are essentially synonymous. But why does `ActiveSheet`, (by itself) which is part of the `Application` object, require the `ActiveWorkbook.` or `Application.` prefix? I've had it behave correctly numerous times without a prefix.

Comment: @A.S.H. Yes the code was in `ThisWorkBook`, that explains it! Thanks. Now I can regain my sanity, or what's left of it.  heh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have 2 instances of Excel running there is only one instance of the Application object. 
Activesheet always returns the same sheet unless you call it inside the ThisWorkbook module when it defaults to Thiswokbook.activesheet rather than Application.Activesheet.
 
Open 2 workbooks and give the worksheets in the 2 workbooks different names (Book1 and Book2). 
 Make Book1 worksheet active 
 Then add this code to an ordinary module in Book2 and to the Thisworkbook module in book 2.

```
Sub activename()
MsgBox Application.ActiveSheet.Name
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveSheet.Name
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

When you run the code in the ordinary module the first 3 msgbox's return Book1 and the 4th returns book2
When you run the code in the Thisworkbook module the first 2 return book1 and the next 2 (Activesheet without a prefix and thisworkbook.activesheet) returns book2